# Move Variable from Class to Class - Dart Flutter

Tags: class, flutter, dart

How do I get the value of the List **data** to be accessed from the class **Details Page**? The value is already set in the constructor via a page route.

```
class TicketDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List data; //<--This is the List

  TicketDetailsPage({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _State();

 }

class _State extends State<TicketDetailsPage> {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return MaterialApp(
    title: "Ticket Details",
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: DetailsPage(),
    );
 }
}
 class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget { 
  //<--Access the list right here-->
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the list to DetailsPage, but before that you have to access TicketDetailsPage data in its state using **widget** in following way.

> widget.data

Now You can pass data and accept data in DetailsPage using constructor as below.

```
class _State extends State<TicketDetailsPage> {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return MaterialApp(
    title: "Ticket Details",
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: DetailsPage(data:widget.data),
    );
 }
}


class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget { 
  final List data; //<--This is the List

   DetailsPage({this.data});
  }
```

Comment: @Abion47 thank you for your suggestion. i generally preferred to answer with explanation, but this time i didn't. However, now added some explanation too.